# How to register a codec in the Spark Mongo Connector in Scala

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark

TL;DR: how do I register a codec in Spark Mongo Connector?

I want to try what I can do with Spark, using Twitter data. Therefor I added all libs to my build.sbt (I know some are not used yet by the example code):

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.1.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.1.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.1.0",
  "org.mongodb.spark" %% "mongo-spark-connector" % "2.0.0",
  "org.apache.bahir" %% "spark-streaming-twitter" % "2.0.1"
)
```

I want to both save the Twitter stream to my MongoDB database and do calculations on it. I tried this (Left out some credential config):

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
    .setAppName(APPNAME)
    .setMaster(MASTER)

  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

  val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(2))

  val stream = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None)

  stream.foreachRDD(_.saveToMongoDB())

  val hashTags = stream.flatMap(status => status.getText.split(" ").filter(_.startsWith("#")))

  val topCounts60 = hashTags.map((_, 1)).reduceByKeyAndWindow(_ + _, Seconds(60))
    .map{case (topic, count) => (count, topic)}
    .transform(_.sortByKey(ascending = false))

  // Print popular hashtags
  topCounts60.foreachRDD(rdd => {
    val topList = rdd.take(10)
    println("\nPopular topics in last 60 seconds (%s total):".format(rdd.count()))
    topList.foreach{case (count, tag) => println("%s (%s tweets)".format(tag, count))}
  })

  ssc.start()
  ssc.awaitTermination()
```

But unfortunatly, I get this exception:

```
org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for interface twitter4j.Status.
```

So I wrote a codec using the `org.bson.codecs.Codec` interface. Now where do I register it?

Comment: You will need to map the stream values to a `Document` as there is no access to the codecs.

Comment: Fighting EXACTLY the same issue! How could mongo-spark-connector be so unfriendly?

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I'm Java dev, so the code here is on Java, not Scala. But I'm sure one can easily adapt it to Scala, in this case additional information about Scala implementation is highly appreciated.*

Ok, so finally I got the answer. There is no *direct* way to do anything with codec registry in MongoSpark. But! Instead of setting codec registry, we can set our own `MongoConnector` when building `MongoSpark` instance. So here I'll provide my code, but it can be another way to do it.

First of all, we need to customize `MongoConnector` (and almost anything what underlies beneath it):

```
public class HackedMongoConnector extends MongoConnector implements Serializable {
    //this is custom CodecRegistry which Spark will use in deserialization
    //transient is important here because Spark loves to serialize anything
    private transient CodecRegistry codecRegistry;

    public HackedMongoConnector(ReadConfig readConfig, CodecRegistry codecRegistry) {
        super(new HackedMongoClientFactory(
            ReadConfig.stripPrefix(readConfig.asOptions()).get(MongoSharedConfig.mongoURIProperty()).get(),
            Integer.parseInt(ReadConfig.stripPrefix(readConfig.asOptions()).get(ReadConfig.localThresholdProperty()).get()),
            codecRegistry
        ));
        this.codecRegistry = codecRegistry;
    }

    @Override
    public CodecRegistry codecRegistry() {
        return codecRegistry;
    }
    //Sources of DefaultMongoClientFactory used and modified here
    private static class HackedMongoClientFactory implements MongoClientFactory {

        private String mongoURI;
        private int localThreshold;
        private transient CodecRegistry codecRegistry;

        public HackedMongoClientFactory(String mongoURI, int localThreshold, CodecRegistry codecRegistry) {
            this.mongoURI = mongoURI;
            this.localThreshold = localThreshold;
            this.codecRegistry = codecRegistry;
        }

        @Override
        public MongoClient create() {
            MongoClientOptions.Builder builder = MongoClientOptions.builder()
                .localThreshold(localThreshold)
                .codecRegistry(codecRegistry);
            MongoClient mongoClient = new HackedMongoClient(new MongoClientURI(mongoURI, builder), codecRegistry);
            return mongoClient;
        }

        private static class HackedMongoClient extends MongoClient {

            private transient CodecRegistry codecRegistry;

            public HackedMongoClient(MongoClientURI uri, CodecRegistry codecRegistry) {
                super(uri);
                this.codecRegistry = codecRegistry;
            }

            //this is the main point: when creating MongoDatabaseImpl, we provide codec immediately
            @Override
            public MongoDatabase getDatabase(String databaseName) {
                return super.getDatabase(databaseName).withCodecRegistry(codecRegistry);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then we can just use it when creating `MongoSpark`:

```
//we create modified connector with custom CodecRegistry
MongoConnector mongoConnector = new HackedMongoConnector(readConfig, fromRegistries(MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry(),
    fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider.builder().register(User.class).build())));


MongoSpark mongoSpark = MongoSpark.builder()
    .javaSparkContext(jsc)
    //here we inject hacked connector 
    .connector(mongoConnector)
    .readConfig(readConfig)
    .build();
```

This solved my problem. I know this question is created year ago, but I hope this will help you, reader, not to spend hours solving similar issue again.

Comment: This is brilliant and saved me a huge headache.  No idea why it had no votes, but you got mine!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One other way is to let Spark infer the schema of your POJO.

```
val mongoRDD = MongoSpark.load(spark.sparkContext, ReadConfig(Map(YOUR PROPERTIES)))
val rdd = mongoRDD.withPipeline(Seq(Document.parse("YOUR PIPELINE QUERY")))

rdd.toDS[POJO]
```

Only drawback your PJO's field names MUST match Mongo's Document fields (nothing's magic)